# How to tell if my data is normal by looking at a histogram and qqnorm of my residuals?

Tags: anova, assumptions, normality-assumption

I have set up a model for a mutli-factor ANOVA, and now I am trying to see if it meets the assumptions. I have a histogram of my residuals, as well as a qqnorm plot. However, I am having trouble interpreting. The histogram looks as if it has outliers, but other than that is fairly symmetric. The qqnorm does not look normal at all for me. How exactly can I tell if it meets the assumptions, or when I need to transform or run a non-parametric test? 
Here are the graphs:
[image]

Comment: Your histogram is obscuring just how extreme both tails are.  The QQ plot makes that clear.  For assistance interpreting QQ plots, please [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=qq+plot).

Comment: Your histogram needs many more bars to see what's going on in that (R's default is generally much too small to use for diagnostic purposes)